# Pandas: count gaps for specific values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count how many times values are not listed in a data frame.

```
1 A
2 A
3 B
4 A
5 C
6 B
7 C
8 A
9 B
```

For `A` that would mean:

1-2: 0 times

2-4: 1 times

4-8: 3 times

For `B` that would mean:

3-6: 2 times

6-9: 2 times

For `C` that would mean:

5-7: 1 times

Is there a clever way to do this with pandas?
The Indexes are actually timestamps, but I think this is not important to the problem.

Comment: How do you decide on those groupings? The `1-2`, `2-4`, etc..

Comment: looks like from one letter to a repeat of the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mark your text and copy it into the clipboard:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard(header=None)
```

you end up with a dataframe with columns 0 and 1. Column 0 has the number, column 1 has the letter.

Running

```
for letter in df[1].unique():
    result = [f'{start}-{end}: {end - start -1} times' 
              for start, end in zip(
                  list(df[df[1] == letter][0]),
                  list(df[df[1] == letter][0])[1:]
                  )
             ]

    print(letter, result)
```

Prints

```
A ['1-2: 0 times', '2-4: 1 times', '4-8: 3 times']
B ['3-6: 2 times', '6-9: 2 times']
C ['5-7: 1 times']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your source data is in `data.text`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=' ', names= ['index', 'blah'])
>>> df_groupby = df.groupby('blah')
>>> for key, item in df_groupby:
...     key
...     pd.cut(df.index.difference(df_groupby.get_group(key).agg('index')), range(0,10,2)).value_counts()
... 
'A'
(0, 2]    1
(2, 4]    1
(4, 6]    2
(6, 8]    1
dtype: int64
'B'
(0, 2]    1
(2, 4]    2
(4, 6]    1
(6, 8]    1
dtype: int64
'C'
(0, 2]    2
(2, 4]    1
(4, 6]    1
(6, 8]    2
dtype: int64
```

Step by step...

A solution for the **related problem** of aggregate counts can be solved with `groupby`.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=' ', names= ['index', 'blah'])

index blah
0      1    A
1      2    A
2      3    B
3      4    A
4      5    C
5      6    B
6      7    C
7      8    A
8      9    B

>>> df.groupby('blah').agg('index').value_counts(bins=range(0,10,2))`

blah  index        
A     (-0.001, 2.0]    2
      (2.0, 4.0]       1
      (6.0, 8.0]       1
      (4.0, 6.0]       0
B     (2.0, 4.0]       1
      (4.0, 6.0]       1
      (-0.001, 2.0]    0
      (6.0, 8.0]       0
C     (4.0, 6.0]       1
      (6.0, 8.0]       1
      (-0.001, 2.0]    0
      (2.0, 4.0]       0
Name: index, dtype: int64
```

To list the indexes that **have** they keys with `groupby`:

```
>>> df_groupby = df.groupby('blah')
>>> for key, item in df_groupby:
>>>    print key, df_groupby.get_group(key).agg('index')

A Int64Index([0, 1, 3, 7], dtype='int64')
B Int64Index([2, 5, 8], dtype='int64')
C Int64Index([4, 6], dtype='int64')
```

Can combine with `pd.cut`

```
>>> pd.cut(df_groupby.get_group('A').agg('index'), range(0,10,2)).value_counts()
(0, 2]    1
(2, 4]    1
(4, 6]    0
(6, 8]    1
dtype: int64
```

And now take the difference

```
>>> pd.cut(df.index.difference(df_groupby.get_group('A').agg('index')), range(0,10,2)).value_counts()

(0, 2]    1
(2, 4]    1
(4, 6]    2
(6, 8]    1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with `groupby`

```
l=[]
for x , y in df.groupby(['1']):

    s1=y['0'].shift(1).iloc[1:].astype(str)+'-'+y['0'].iloc[1:].astype(str)
    s2=y['0'].diff().dropna()-1
    l.append(dict(zip(s1,s2)))

l
Out[351]: 
[{'1.0-2': 0.0, '2.0-4': 1.0, '4.0-8': 3.0},
 {'3.0-6': 2.0, '6.0-9': 2.0},
 {'5.0-7': 1.0}]
```

---

Basically `diff` is  what you need

```
df.groupby(['1'])['0'].diff().dropna()-1
Out[354]: 
1    0.0
3    1.0
5    2.0
6    1.0
7    3.0
8    2.0
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

I am using for loop just to create the format you need .